# querying database with python sqlachemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have postgresql database in my local and am querying it using the following python code.

```
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))


def main():
    flights = db.execute("select origin,destination,duration from flight").fetchall()
    for flight in flights:
        print(f"{flight.origin} to {flight.destination}, is {flight.duration} minutes")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What do i put for the value of **DATABASE_URL** for mycase??

Comment: Are you using any database system? If not go with sqlite, which stores data in `.db` file. `DATABASE_URL` should be then `sqlite:///tmp/test.db`

Comment: am using postgresql

Comment: So use: `postgresql//user:password@localhost/database_name`

Comment: It is not working, but when i remove the 'os.getenv' , it works

Comment: I think that because you are not properly setting the environment variable `DATABASE_URL`. You can omit that, and set it directly. Glad it worked.

Comment: If you find my answer helpfull, please upvote it. Thanks!

Comment: your answer solved my problem, but it is in the comment section, how do i upvote it??

Comment: your answer solved my problem, but it is in the comment section, how do i upvote it??

Comment: You can upvote this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54964332/8916412

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need set your database url correctly. For PostgreSQL it is:

```
postgresql//user:password@localhost/database_name
```